# Powershell script outputting Chinese characters when it's not meant to

Tags: powershell

I've written a script which does a benchmark on the time taken to run **any** command that I input, such as `ping google.com -n 1` and I'm having trouble with the output.

When I run the code in an interactive shell, it is fine, but when I run it as a powershell `.ps1` script, it puts out chinese characters like this:

> 〱䘠扥ㄠ㨰㈵瀉湩⁧潧杯敬挮浯ⴠ⁮ऱ㌲⸹ㄷ㔳獭਍

That is the "result" from `ping google.com -n 1`

Needless to say, I'm a little confused as to why it is doing this...

Any ideas?

---

This is my code:

```
$command = Read-Host "Enter command"

"DateTime`tCommand`tTime Taken" | Out-file "$($command -replace '[^A-Za-z]','').csv"

While (1) {

    $time = date -f "dd MMM HH:mm"

    $cmdtime = [string](
    Measure-Command {iex $command}
    ).TotalMilliseconds + "ms"

   "$($time)`t$($command)`t$($cmdtime)" | Out-File "$($command -replace '[^A-Za-z]','').csv" -a

   Sleep 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for this happening is because the first `Out-File` did not have the `-Encoding ASCII` parameter set, resulting in a file being created with a Non-ASCII encoding!

Comment: What's the value of `$OutputEncoding` ?